# Passing parameter from angular js for a POST web api method

Tags: angularjs, http-post, asp.net-web-api2

I have used a sample code for an upload control.

Web API call from angularJs controller is given below

```
var uploader = $scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
    url: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/api/FileUpload/UploadFile',
    data:{seldocType:"1"}
});
```

THe post WEB api method is

```
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult UploadFile(string seldocType)
    {..}
```

In the browser, FileUploader obj had below info along with others

```
 data: Object ->seldocType: "1"
method: "POST"
url: "http://localhost:90/api/FileUpload/UploadFile"
```

The call works fine if I remove the seldocType paramter( in API as well as controller).
When i try to add this parameter, api call does not happen.
I am assuming i am not passing the parameter in the right way. Can you please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an object as your post method argument instead of string.

First create a class with `seldocType` as its propery and keep that class as an argument of your post method.

```
Class Document { public string SeldocType {get;set;} }
```

Now use this class in your post method as an argument

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult UploadFile(Document document)
{..}
```

> POST method takes object type as a parameter.

Comment: THank you, data would still be passed as data:{seldocType:"1"} correct?

Comment: Yes. No issue with your client side calling.

Comment: As you can see in your browser,   data: Object ->seldocType: "1" data itself is passed as an object type to the server.

Comment: [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult UploadFile(VMSelectedDocument selectedDocument)
        {..}

Comment: In a different class file, public class VMSelectedDocument
    {
        public string seldocType { get; set; } 
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83307/discussion-between-samuel-and-adarsh-k).